# Unable to start my custom flow because of java.io.NotSerializableException

Tags: corda

I am having this error when I am calling my custom flow through my RPCClient.

```
@PostMapping(value="/flows/issue")
private fun issuance(@RequestBody note : Money){
    val matchingParties = proxy.partiesFromName(note.owner, false)
    if(matchingParties.size != 1)
        throw IllegalArgumentException("Enter a valid Party name")
    val recipient = matchingParties.single()
    proxy.startFlow(::IssueMoney, note.currency, note.amount, recipient)
}
```

My  custom flow is another class with the classpath net.corda.server.flows . I have annotated it as @CordaSerializable and added the "-parameters" in the java compiler.

The error at the console at my node was

> Serialization failed direction="Deserialize", type="java.lang.Class", msg="Could not instantiate net.corda.server.flows.IssueMoney - not on the classpath", corda  ClassChain="java.util.List<*> -> net.corda.server.flows.IssueMoney"

The error at my webserver was

java.io.NotSerializableException: net.corda.server.flows.IssueMoney was not found by the node, check the Node containing the CorDapp that implements net.corda.server.flows.IssueMoney is loaded and on the Classpath

Answer (score 0):

1. `CordaSerializable` is an annotation that you put on a class that gets sent/received by your flow; for instance you have some custom class `MyClass` that your initiator sends to the responder; you mark `MyClass` with `@CordaSerializable`; this way when your initiator calls `send`, it gets checkpointed (i.e. all its data is written to disk), part of that data is your `MyClass` which with that annotation allows Corda to serialize it (when flow is checkpointed) and deserialize (when the flows resumes). So in summary, remove the annotation from the flow.
2. I assume that the error happened because somewhere in your flow you're using `java.util.List` (that's what shows in your error message); `List` is an interface, so Corda won't know how to serialize/deserialize it, instead you have to use an implementation of the `List` interface like `ArrayList` or `LinkedList`.

Comment: I am using listOf() to wrap which is required.
```
 "subFlow(IssueTokens(listOf(amount of token issuedBy ourIdentity heldBy recipient)))" 
```
Is there any alternative way to use issueTokens

Comment: I tried using finance module instead and used CashIssueAndPayement flow but same type of error was there. THE ERROR WAS ::::: 
 amqp.DeserializationInput. - Serialization failed direction="Deserialize", type="java.lang.Class", msg="Could not instantiate net.corda.finance.flows.CashIssueAndPaymentFlow - not on the classpath", ClassChain="java.util.List<*> -> net.corda.finance.flows.CashIssueAndPaymentFlow :::::: I think its about the Classpath not found . But I am not able to infer anything from it.

Comment: Finance CorDapp is deprecated, do not use it. Are you sure your node has all the required CorDapps installed? When you open your node's `cordapps` folder, does it have the jar files of your modules, plus the jar files of the Tokens SDK (i.e. `tokens-contracts`, `tokens-selection`, `tokens-workflows`)?

Comment: Also other than calling `listOf()` inside the `IssueTokens` sub-flow; are you sure you're not using `List` anywhere else in your main flow?

Comment: The required jars are there and I am not using  List in the main flow. I ran the " flow list" command in my node and my custom flows were not there . I think my nodes are not able to locate the flow. How can I specify the flows for my nodes ?

Comment: You are saying you're using `List` in your main flow; does that mean you have something like `List myList = new List();`? If so, you should replace `List` with `ArrayList` or `LinkedList` like I explained before.

Comment: If your custom flows are not showing, it means your node didn't load your CorDapp. Open the log of your node (located inside `your-node/logs/node.log` and search for `loaded cordapps` and see the names of CorDapps that were loaded, is your flows jar among them? If not, you have to see why; for instance for `contracts` CorDapps, if they are not signed and your node is running in production mode (inside `node.conf` you have `devMode = false`) then the node won't load any unsigned `contracts` CorDapp.

Comment: Also I don't know how you're logging to your node's shell; it could be that the RPC user that you're using to login doesn't have permissions to run your custom flows. But if you're just using the shell where you ran `java -jar corda.jar` to start the node, then that doesn't apply.